# Using the ng-repeat directive on a table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a static HTML table that I'd like to make dynamic. Is ng-repeat the correct directive to be using? I'm new to angular so I'm not really sure how I would do this. Would I create a controller and put the HTML template for the table in the controller or would I do something like have name/value pairs like "Track Name" and set that to "Track 1" etc? Pretty lost. HTML for the table is below. Thanks in advance.

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Track Name</th>
    <th>Track Duration</th>
    <th>Options</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Track 1</td>
    <td>3:00</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Track 2</td>
    <td>3:20</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You can certainly use `ng-repeat`.

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="AlbumController">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Track Name</th>
      <th>Track Duration</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="track in album">
      <td>{{track.no}}</td>
      <td>{{track.name}}</td>
      <td>{{track.dur}}</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


myApp.controller('AlbumController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.album = [
    { no: 1, name: "Track 1", dur: "1:00" },
    { no: 2, name: "Track 2", dur: "3:00" },
  ];
}]);
```

EDIT: Mistake has been corrected. Sorry about that.

Comment: Like this you repeat the `tbody` tag which is not valid. The `ng-repeat` should be on the `tr` tag.

Comment: You need a controller to use the ng-repeat directive. Controller can either be added through routes (check out angular ui-router) or <div ng-controller="MyCtrlr">

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing how you can make your table more dynamic using multiple `ng-repeat` so that as your objects gain more properties, your table will update accordingly.

HTML

```
    <table class="table" ng-controller="TableCtrl">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in tableThings[0]">{{key}}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in tableThings">
            <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">{{value}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

JS

```
angular.module('angular-tests', [])
    .controller('TableCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.tableThings = [
        {
          Number: 1,
          'Track Name': 'Track 1',
          'Track Duration': '3:00'
        },
        {
          Number: 2,
          'Track Name': 'Track 2',
          'Track Duration': '3:20'
        }
      ];
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll read some more documentation on the directive so I know what's going on.

Comment: Np. Welcome to SO. `ng-repeat="item in tableThings"` iterates through the array of `tableThings` and then `ng-repeat="(key, value) in item"` iterates through each `key` and `value` inside each `item` (the objects inside the tableThings array).